# Send POST request in d3 (with d3-fetch)

Tags: javascript, json, post, d3.js, fetch

I need to send a JSON object to a remote service via an HTTP POST request. Recent versions of d3.js use [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) for gathering data (from file or via network) instead of [d3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request). I found plenty of examples ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493758/xhr-post-request-using-d3), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964726/d3-how-to-properly-pass-request-body-in-a-post-request) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887386/multipart-post-request-with-d3-json-d3-xhr)) for earlier versions of the library, but nothing for the latest version (as of August 2018). The [documentation for d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) also lacks an example how to set up the [RequestInit](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit) object such that a POST request is sent. Did anyone do this already?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround I meanwhile found using `d3.text`.

```js
var request = d3.text("http://localhost:8080/service?action=store", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    body: "entry=" + JSON.stringify(playerData)
});
```

I needed to set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in order for the JSON payload to be sent. Stringifying the JSON and wrapping it as value to some arbitrary key was necessary so that the request gets though. I am in control of the backend service's source code and could change it to read the JSON directly, if it would be possible to send it just like so.

Using `d3.json` instead with the plain JSON as body and the respective Content-Type (compare [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)) did not work: the request wont include any payload.

My solution looks rather complicated so I guess there must be a cleaner way and I am eager to accept any working improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify the method you're using, let's suppose you're using `d3.json` (probably, since you want to send a JSON).

If you look at the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch), you'll see:

> d3.json(input[, init])

Where `init` is the `init` object, as you already know. From the [Fetch documentation](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit) for the allowed fields we can see:

> method: A string to set request’s method.

And the most important:

> A request has an associated method (a method). Unless stated otherwise it is `GET`.

Therefore, what you need is something like this:

```
d3.json(input, {method: "post"})
```

Among other necessary fields. This is an interesting example (not D3-related): https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/fetch-api/fetch-post.html

Comment: This is as far as I got with `d3.json`. However, I couldn't find a way to include the JSON object into the request. I'll post the workaround I found below. Maybe you can extend your solution to achieve the same thing in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

I had success using this:

```html
d3.json("http://localhost:8545", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      method: "eth_blockNumber",
      params: [],
      id: 1
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Parsing the json returned by the resource:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dsv.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-fetch.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    d3.json("<url>", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data.body))
    })
</script>
```